# What do I have to import to use the DataContractAttribute?

Tags: wcf

As stated in the question. what do I have to import to use the DataContractAttribute?

as i have generated the file using the svcutil, it generated a file with that attribute and after adding it to my winform app, there seems to be an missing reference.

```
Using ????
```

anyone can help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a reference to the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly and then add the following using directive:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```